# Deep Populate With Condition

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a Message Collection which contains messages, models look like this.

```
var MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    groupId: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' },
});

var GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   type: String,
   groupMembers: [{ "user": { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' } }],
});
```

Here is my code:

```
 Message.find({ 'groupId': { $in: groupIds } })
.populate(
{ path: 'groupId', select: 'groupMembers type name level', 
populate: { path: 'groupMembers.user', select: 'name _id photo', model: 'User' } })
```

How can I populate **groupMembers.user** only if **groupId.type** matches with a condition?

I've tried this but :-(

```
{match:"groupId.type":'individual'}
```

Comment: Try `Message.find({ 'groupId': { $in: groupIds } }).populate({ path: 'groupId', match: { type: 'indiviual' }, select: 'groupMembers type name level', 
populate: { path: 'groupMembers.user', select: 'name _id photo', model: 'User'  } })`

Comment: @Mikey: thanks for the comment, I tried that, but **groupId** returns null for other types.